# fancy box prev and next buttons // how to show in some and not others

Tags: fancybox-2

I have 3 fancy box slide shows in ►[this page](http://camandbenny.com/work)◀

1 in the portraits.
2 in the porthole.
3 coming from the anything slider itself.

The anything slider is in a ul - but I don't want previos and next buttons to show on that one.

Since they all use the same CSS, I can't just hide them.  So I would imagine I would have to do it in the javaScript... But I can't find anything in the documentation.

Do any of you have any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `rel` attribute from the links that you don't want to have next/prev buttons

Answer (score 1):

remove or hide previous next functionality from fancybox

.ui-widget-overlay
         {
            opacity: 0.9 !important;
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #111111 !important;
         }
         .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span 
         {
            /* .... */
            visibility: hidden !important;
         }
         .fancybox-next
         {
             z-index:-999 !important;
         }
          .fancybox-prev
         {
             z-index:-999 !important;
         }